# error bash extracting second column of a matched pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to search for a pattern and from the results i am extracting just the second column. The command works well in command line but not inside a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set a = grep 'NM_033356' test.txt | awk '{ print $2 }'
echo $a
```

It doesnt print any output at all.

**Input**

```
NM_033356  2
NM_033356  5
NM_033356  7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
set a = grep 'NM_033356' test.txt | awk '{ print $2 }'
echo $a
```

**Change it to:**

```
#!/bin/bash
a="$(awk '$1=="NM_033356"{ print $2 }' test.txt)"
echo "$a"
```

Code changes are based on your sample input.

Comment: still doesnt print any results. It matches well in the command line but not inside the bash script

Comment: Can you run the script in debug mode? Do `bash -x scriptname` and post the result in your question. Also post the command line output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

.......

```
a="$(awk '/NM_033356/ { print $2 }' test.txt)"
```

Comment: That line doesn't print anything.

Comment: i echo'd the variable.. then it didnt print anything too

Comment: Then it isn't matching anything.

Comment: @Vignesh Didn't you want to assign the result to a variable?

Comment: yea i want to assign it to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a=`grep 'NM_033356' test.txt | awk '{ print $2 }'`
```